Further Approximation Based Control Examples
Does anyone know where I can find more approximation-based control examples such as example 12.3 from Chapter 12 of Lavretsky and Wise's "Robust Adaptive Control with Aerospace Applications?" I have attached the relevant chapter below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BIsGcZhgWmj5sRryMn9O0G16knO8xXNx/view?usp=sharing

People are less likely to click on external links. Consider typing up (not a screenshot of text) one of the examples from the book directly into the question with appropriate citation. Use the [edit] option below the question to add the example. If you are a new user please visit the [tour] page and see what type of questions are suitable for this stack exchange and make modifications to the questions if necessary.

Other text books in the field?
